# function and linked list

Tags: c, pointers

I am wondering why the linked list is still the same after calling this function. The head address is not reassigned to head -> next? Is this call by reference since a pointer variable is passed to the function?

```
typedef struct list{int data; struct list *next;} list;
void iterate_test(list* h)
    {h = h -> next;}`
```

Comment: `h` behaves like a local variable.

Comment: Because `h` is passed-by-value.